# How can I fix this errors in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, typescript

pls help me. Thanks
I tried to deploy a server Nodejs, I changed the Server port to

server.listen({port: PORT || 3000}, '0.0.0.0')

but heroku logs --tail showed still error log:

```
2020-09-29T08:53:01.791207+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-09-29T08:53:03.681698+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-29T08:53:03.681721+00:00 app[web.1]: > buddy-app-backend@1.0.0 start /app
2020-09-29T08:53:03.681722+00:00 app[web.1]: > node dist/index.js
2020-09-29T08:53:03.681722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-29T08:53:05.651099+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-09-29 08:53:05,648 INFO [TSK] TASK timer Started!
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666159+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666160+00:00 app[web.1]: at getNodeRequestOptions (/app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1284:9)
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666160+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1370:19
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666161+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666161+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.fetch (/app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1367:9)
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666161+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.fetch (/app/node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/node-ponyfill.js:10:20)
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666162+00:00 app[web.1]: at BatchedGraphQLClient.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/http-link-dataloader/dist/src/BatchedGraphQLClient.js:59:46)
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666162+00:00 app[web.1]: at step (/app/node_modules/http-link-dataloader/dist/src/BatchedGraphQLClient.js:40:23)
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666163+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.next (/app/node_modules/http-link-dataloader/dist/src/BatchedGraphQLClient.js:21:53)
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666163+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/http-link-dataloader/dist/src/BatchedGraphQLClient.js:15:71
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666165+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666260+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
2020-09-29T08:53:05.666369+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2020-09-29T08:54:02.094592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-09-29T08:54:02.111385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-09-29T08:54:02.175166+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-09-29T08:54:02.214444+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: I guess you should remove the second argument - '0.0.0.0' server.listen({port: PORT || 3000})

Comment: I tried like you said before, I just have bought a new server aws and then everything works oke

Comment: Thanks I resolved it with aws server already ! thank you